# Different ip when checking on whatsmyip.com and ipchicken.com

Tags: networking

In whatsmyip.com it shows my current public IP, while in ipchicken.com it shows a random ip from france.
Am I infected with malware or did something happen? I have checked with wireshark to see if any packets are sent out to the destination of the france IP but none was found. I am really confused.

Comment: This is entirely possible if you are behind a Carrier Grade NAT router with multiple public IPs. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT

Comment: @acejavelin could be possible but after ages of checking my IP, this is the first time this has happened, so it has got me worried.

Comment: Does the hostname and other information match, are the IP's likely within the same subnet? Probably, I wouldn't be overly concerned unless you have other problems as well.

Comment: What to you see on this page?...https://www.iplocation.net/

Comment: @acejavelin It does not match, I have no clue if the IP's are within the same subnet, I have never had an IP out of my country, from other cities... Yes, but not another country.

Comment: @Moab I see my actual public IP and my country